# setting a value in `about:config` page from bash (no gui available)

Tags: bash, firefox, centos-7

On my VPS (centos 7) that has **no gui** at all, I'm trying to set `intl.charset.fallback.utf8_for_file` to `true` on `about:config` page.
Is this possible **from terminal**? like editing some `.ini` file in firefox folder or running firefox with some command line option in `--headless` mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search in your home directory file `prefs.js` (usually `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js`) and in this directory edit file `user.js` (the file may not yet exist) and add:

```
user_pref("intl.charset.fallback.utf8_for_file", true);
```

Comment: thanks.. but is there any variable like `intl.charset.fallback.utf8_for_file` but for online files (like webpages) because unfortunately `intl.charset.fallback.utf8_for_file` actually works only for  offline files.
the default character encoding in firefox is westeren I need to change it to utf-8 without gui. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I suggest to start a new question.

Comment: I did, thank u https://superuser.com/questions/1480227/make-utf-8-default-character-encoding-in-firefox-through-aboutconfig