# make utf-8 default character encoding in firefox through `about:config`

Tags: firefox

I want to know if there is a variable like `intl.charset.fallback.utf8_for_file` **but for online files** (like webpages) to set the default character encoding to utf-8 (because unfortunately `intl.charset.fallback.utf8_for_file` actually works only for offline files). I need to do it through `about:config` because my VPS have **no GUI** & I'm using firefox in `--headless` mode .

Answer (score 0):

There is not. (Source: I wrote the code.)

If the encoding depended on user-side configuration, people would create content that would look right for the author but wrong for other site visitors.

Comment: It looks like even `intl.charset.fallback.utf8_for_file` doesn't work anymore?

Comment: That pref is obsolete. If a file at a `file:` URL is actually in UTF-8, it is treated as UTF-8.

Comment: and there is no way to override the decision of firefox to treat it as UTF-8 or Windows-1252?

Comment: If the file is UTF-8, there is no way to override it as windows-1252. If the file isn't UTF-8, there is no way to override it as UTF-8.